# Adding checked attribute to html tag with JSP

Tags: html, jsp, input, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to add `checked` to a html input tag with JSP but without luck.

Currently I have this:

```
isBoy = "";
isGirl = "checked";

<inp:radio value="first" checked="<%=isGirl%>"/>
<inp:radio value="second" checked="<%=isBoy%>"/>
```

But that just returns:

```
<input value="first" checked="checked"/>
<input value="second" checked />
```

Which result in the second value being considered checked in the client.

I tried removing the `checked="..."` part and just go with `<inp:radio ... "<%=isGirl%>" />` or `<inp:radio ... <%=isGirl%> />` Both return errors.

Is there any way to add the `checked` attribute with JSP so I end up with this?:

```
<input value="first" checked />
<input value="second" />
```

All recommendations are welcome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove checked attribute if you don't want it to be checked.Try:

```
 <%
    isBoy = "";
isGirl = "checked='checked'";
 %>
<inp:radio value="first" <%=isGirl%>"/>
<inp:radio value="second" <%=isBoy%>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with both
`<inp:radio value <%=isGirl%>" />` and `<inp:radio value "<%=isGirl%>" />` But still getting an error.